# Generate query for Spring method with @GraphQLQuery

Tags: spring, graphql, graphql-java

I have method:

```
   @GraphQLQuery(name = "events", description = "get all events")
   public List<String> getEvents() {
         return List.of("test", "test2");
    }
```

I need to create query for clients. below example not work:

```
query events{
  events{
    ... String
  }
}
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this annotation - @QueryMapping